# How to see all the changes that I did to the code since my last push?

Tags: git

I want to know what exactly I did with the code (what files have I edited, what have I added and so on). In more detail, I want to compare my current local repository with the remote repository. However, I do not want to see what other people have changed. In only want to know what will be my contribution if I push. To be clear, while editing my code I have pulled several times and I also "played" with the local branches.

Answer (score 2):

[`git diff <commit>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) allows you to compare your current commit against another commit. The commit can be on your origin, as well as local.

So, for example, if I have a development branch and a mixed history of regular commits and merges with the remote's master, then I can use:

```
git fetch # to get the most recent version of origin's state
git diff origin/master
```

to see the differences between my local development branch and the remote's master.

Keep in mind that every commit is a full copy of the repo. `diff` just compares the differences between two commits (full copies), so the history of the branch doesn't really matter. If `origin/master` is ahead of your development branch, that'll be reflected in your diff results, but if you are up to date, then `diff` will show you only the changes you've made locally.

Answer (score 1):

`git log master...origin/master --author="Your Username"` will show the difference between your master branch and the remote master branch in terms of commits, but only if the commit was authored by yourself.

You can use the `--patch` switch to see exactly which lines of code have been updated.

Ensure you do a `git fetch` first to make sure you have the latest information about the remote branch.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you're on the master branch and create two files `src1.c`, `src.2` and modified `something.c`.

You didn't commit the changes what you did. In order to see all the changes what you did since last push. Use `git status': this will give you the working status of your tree.

I prefer  `git status -s`: Here -s flag will give the output in short format.

You have mentioned that you have pulled several times.

> I have pulled several times and I also "played" with the local
>   branches.

During that process, if someone has modified the same file what you worked on it then you will get the merge conflicts.Here you need to resolve the merge conflicts.

The only way to save changes what you did is `git commit - m "commit_message"`. After `git commit` you can use git diff to see the difference between two commits.

One way to see the diff between previous commit(accessed using HEAD^) and the head is

```
git diff HEAD^ HEAD
```